# Are customers with the Square API shared between merchants that leverage the same App

Tags: oauth, share, square

I'm currently experimenting with the [Square Customer API](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/customers-api), to create an application that would be used by multiple discrete businesses. However, the app experience for the customer would be the same from business to business. Is there the capability to share customers between merchants with the Square API? Allowing for stored cards to be used at any business that leverage the application.

I understand that using the OAuth token provided by the merchant during application signup is used with all calls to the API but could the application token be used to store the customer with the application itself instead of the merchant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time, all customers are visible only to the merchant account that created them, so there's no way to share the customer between merchants other than to re-create them at each merchant.